# Dropdown navigation with same width as parent navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I already  tried "width: 100%;" but the dropdown element then gets the same width as the whole page. I'm working with floats so maybe that needs a different approach?

I swear I've looked at similar questions but none of the solutions there worked for me. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? You can find the jsfiddle with all of the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashielf/37x0nzap/). I currently "solved" the problem with a fixed width.

Here is the HTML for the navi:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navi"> 
            <ul class="nav-elements">
                <li><a href="./index.html" title="The Homepage of Story Bat" class="current" tabindex="1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="./active-stories/index.html" title="Active Stories" tabindex="2">Ongoing Stories</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" title="">Sublink</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="">Another Sublink with a long text</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="./sleeping-stories/index.html" title="Sleeping Stories" tabindex="3">Sleeping Stories</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" title="">Sublink</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" title="">Another Sublink</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="./news/index.html" title="Updates about Story Bat" tabindex="4">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="./about-faq/index.html" title="Information about Story Bat" tabindex="5">About/FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.navi {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.navi ul {
    padding-left: 0; /* Navi aligned left */
    margin: 0;
}
.navi li {
    background: #808080;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em 0.2em 0.8em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
/* nav-elements for dropdown-menus */
.nav-elements ul {
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
}
.nav-elements li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 9.25em;
    margin-left: -0.85em; /* to counter the padding in .navi li */
}
.nav-elements li:focus, 
.nav-elements li:hover { /* main navi gets shadow while dropdown is active */
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* kind of a glow effect */
}
.nav-elements li:focus ul, /* show the submenu when user focues (e.g. via tab) the parent li [doesn't work?]*/
.nav-elements li:hover ul { /* show the submenu when user hovers over the parent li */
    left:auto; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
    text-shadow: none; /* dropdown doesn't inherit shadow from main-navi*/
}
.nav-elements ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

Comment: use width:100% on ul and then position:relative on parent li. just remove extra padding/maring from child li and  you are done.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/37x0nzap/5/ ..when i will be done i will post as answer.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your issue that you don't want to use fixed width then please check my [Updted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/37x0nzap/13/)

I have  used `width:100%` so it will change according to parent ul. What you need is to change width:100% and `position:relative` or parent li(.navi li) and then i removed margin-right as it was extra and you got the result.

**Updated**
As i have used `position:relative` so width:100 is taking width inside the border so you are missing 2px gap so just for workaround i have used `width:101%`. Please check my updated fiddle.

let me know if its what you need. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked your fiddle but it doesn't correspond with your proposal. I still see the "width: 9.25em" in the ".nav-elements li ul". 
However, I took your input and put it into [a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashielf/ryvk5jmp/1/). It looks better and doesn't need a fixed width so huge step forward! :) There still is a little gap between the width of the parent element and the width of the dropwdown. Can you see what's still amiss?

Comment: i have added my css under leo's css comment..ok give me 2 min plz

Comment: Thank you very much! Your changes were what was needed:
.navi li{position:relative;}
.nav-elements li ul {width:101%;}
.nav-elements ul li{margin-right:0px;}

Comment: Addendum: For a perfect alignment of the dropdown elements I had to add: .align {margin-right: -2px;} ==> ".align" is a class I assigned to the "li"-elements of the first dropdown-list ("Ongoing stories"). The second dropwdown-list ("Sleeping stories") doesn't need this adjustment. 
If somebody knows why I'm glad for the help but I can live with this workaround.

Comment: @Ashielf, as i told you, i have used position:absolute and then used width:100% so it will only take width inside of border becuase of position and thats why you have to add -2px for perfect alignment.

Comment: Alright. I think it's better to use the -2px since the 101% doesn't align perfectly. Thank you very much for the help, I got a better understanding of those attributes now.

Comment: Happy to help :) and please upvote the answer if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

your second ul element can just be wide as the li element around it. try this:

```css
#subMenuFoo {
  display: none;
}

#foo:hover ~ #subMenuFoo {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-elements">
  <a href="" id="foo">foo</a>
  <div id="subMenuFoo">
    <a href="">bar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

--
please mind the gap